# Why Are My Default Property Values Still Showing as Parameters in Init()?

Tags: swift, protocols, protocol-oriented

I have a protocol that describes a marine water parameter that needs tested:

```swift
protocol Parameter {

    var name: String { get }
    var unit: Unit { get }
    var value: Double { get }

}
```

I have a struct, `Calcium`, that conforms to `Parameter`:

```swift
struct Calcium: Parameter {

    var name: String = "Calcium"
    var unit: Unit = UnitDispersion.partsPerMillion
    var value: Double

}
```

Since the `name` and `unit` parameters of `Calcium` have default values, why do I need to provide them in the `init` method? Shouldn't I only need to provide a value for `value`?

I am trying to understand protocol-oriented-programming and would really appreciate a little guidance here.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. This has nothing whatever to do with protocols.
2. You do not have to provide an initializer for anything but the `value`. But you have not provided *any* initializer. Therefore the only initializer you have is the one provided *automatically*, and that initializer is the memberwise initializer which wants parameters for all your properties.

If you don't like that, write an initializer yourself:

```
struct Calcium: Parameter {
    var name: String = "Calcium"
    var unit: Unit = UnitDispersion.partsPerMillion
    var value: Double
    init(value:Double) {self.value = value}
}
```

Now it is legal to say:

```
let c = Calcium(value:2)
```

Comment: Regarding the next obvious question of "why doesn't Swift…" see https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0018-flexible-memberwise-initialization.md which discusses both proposals for changing this behavior and links to the rationale for why it hasn't so far been changed.

Comment: @RobNapier Cool, thanks for adding that. So we could call that the "intelligent memberwise initializer"... :)

Comment: So if I have, let's say, 20 more water parameter structs that conform to the Parameter protocol, I still need to implement the same initializer for every struct? Is that something that can be added in a protocol extension, or would I be better off just adding that initializer to the protocol and requiring that it be implemented by everything that conforms to the Parameter protocol?

Comment: @NickKohrn Excellent question. Try it and see! :)